# Symfony perform action when user login

Tags: php, listener, symfony

I wan't to do update action (add +1 to login count and update last login timestamp) to database when user is logged in successfully. Using Symfony 3

I have added lister:

```
// src/AppBundle/Listener/SecurityListener.php

namespace AppBundle\Listener;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
#use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class SecurityListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, EntityManager $doctrine)
    {

    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        if ( $this->tokenStorage->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') ) {
            if( $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser() )
                var_dump($user);
            else {
                var_dump('nej');
            }
        }
    /**
     * Update lastLogin and loginCount for user in database
     */
    //  $em->
    }
}
```

app/config/services.yml:

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value
  account.security_listener.class: AppBundle\Listener\SecurityListener

services:
#    service_name:
#        class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
#        arguments: ["@another_service_name", "plain_value", "%parameter_name%"]
  account.security_listener:
      class: %account.security_listener.class%
      arguments: ['@security.token_storage', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
      tags:
          - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

I'm getting error `Error: Call to a member function isGranted() on null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')` is available on Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker. If you want to check if is user authenticated via token (as in your `SecurityListener` class), change your `onSecurityInteractiveLogin` method with this:

```
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    if ($event->getAuthenticationToken()->isAuthenticated()) {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        var_dump($user);
    }

/**
 * Update lastLogin and loginCount for user in database
 */

//  $em->

}
```

Comment: What is the service for this InteractiveLoginEvent ? I get error: `The service "account.security_listener" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.interactiveloginevent".` I tried also with security.event

Comment: You don't need to modify your services.yml. You just need to update the `onSecurityInteractiveLogin` method of your `AppBundle\Listener\SecurityListener` class.

Comment: I get error: `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to AppBundle\Listener\SecurityListener::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent, none given` when I copy your modified code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forgot to :

```
public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, EntityManager $doctrine)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
```

???